# How can set Hint Text in code?

Tags: java, android, hint, textinputlayout

I have:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ti_amount_layout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:theme="@style/BlueAccentColor">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_amount"
                        style="@style/EditTextRedBorder"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/product_selector_width"
                        android:background="@drawable/contacts_bg_mess"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/palette_contacts_send_mess_text"
                        android:textColor="@color/palette_black"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal">

                    </EditText>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And I need add **Hint Text**, If I added hint text in xml, in EditText:

```
android:hint="@string/s_amount"
```

all nice, but if I add `etAmount.setHint(R.string.s_amount);` in code - String (hint text) does not popup ((, Why?

Comment: where do you use the setHint function in your code ? Can you show it to us ?

Comment: Use `etAmount.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.s_amount));` You are trying to pass it the resource ID instead of getting the value the resource ID identifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the hint to the TextInputLayout instead.

```
mTextInputLayout.setHint("your hint here");
```